# Pass dynamic key value in grapql query React Native

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-query

hello all I develope application in react native with qraphql so here is my one of the query

```
{
 products(
 filter: {category_uid: {eq: "Mw=="}, bestseller: {eq: "44"}}
 sort: {name: ASC}
 pageSize: 10
 currentPage: 1
  ) {
total_count
items {
  uid
  name
  sku
  boutique_name
  small_image {
    url
    label
   }
  }
 }
}
```

So in above query there is one parmas bestseller and it's value {eq: "44"} so I have 5 categories right now bestseller, top_rated. new_arrivals, trending somenting like that. So If I choose new_arrival at that time query need to change like below

```
{
 products(
 filter: {category_uid: {eq: "Mw=="}, new_arrival: {eq: "45"}}
 sort: {name: ASC}
 pageSize: 10
 currentPage: 1
  ) {
total_count
items {
  uid
  name
  sku
  boutique_name
  small_image {
    url
    label
   }
  }
 }
}
```

It means key value is dynamic but when I pass as dynamic at that time it is converted into string which is through error

```
{
 products(
 filter: {category_uid: {eq: "Mw=="}, "new_arrival": {eq: "44"}}
 sort: {name: ASC}
 pageSize: 10
 currentPage: 1
  ) {
total_count
items {
  uid
  name
  sku
  boutique_name
  small_image {
    url
    label
   }
  }
 }
}
```

So anyone have idea how I can pass filter parameter dynamic key value in my above query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the filter object and can pass it as variables like below

```js
variables: {
   filter: {
      category_uid: {eq: "Mw==" },
      ...( isBestSeller ? { bestseller: { eq: "44" } } : { new_arrival: { eq: "45" } })
  }
}
```

and pass the filter variable in query

```js
{
  products(
    filter: $filter,
    sort: {
      name: ASC
    }
    pageSize: 10 currentPage: 1
  ) {
    total_count
    items {
      uid
      name
      sku
      boutique_name
      small_image {
        url
        label
      }
    }
  }
}
```